# Calling Storyboard inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I am getting a constant error with my code that I can;t figure out.

> No applicable name scope exists to resolve the name 'gridCallLog'.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContentDetail">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="StoryCallLogOn">
                <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="gridCallLog">
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0,10,23.04"/>
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0,0,10,200"/>
                </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="borderCallLog">
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,402,10,23.04"/>
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0,225,10,23.04"/>
                </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Height="500" >
            <Border Margin="10,5,0,10" BorderBrush="Transparent" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1" Width="1050">
                <StackPanel Margin="5,5,9,5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <dx:DXTabControl Width="850" Margin="5,5,0,0">
                        <dx:DXTabItem Header="Call Log">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <dxg:GridControl x:Name="gridCallLog" Height="400" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainStack,Path=DataContext.CallLog}"  
                                dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2010Blue" Margin="0,0,10,0" SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=MainStack,Path=DataContext.SelectedCallLog,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                    <dxg:GridControl.Columns >


<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ElementName=MainStack,Path=DataContext.CallLogOnCommand}" />
</i:EventTrigger>
<ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MainStack,Path=DataContext.CallLogOn, Mode=OneWay}" Value="ON">
    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryCallLogOn}" ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
</ei:DataTrigger>
```

The storyboard is getting called with no problem. But for some reason even though the storyboard is in the DataTemplate.Resources it cannot see my GridControl named gridCallLog.
Any pointers would be gratefully accepted. Scott

Comment: have you tried to put your Storyboard in one of the control insode the DataTemplate?

Comment: You mean move it inside a stack panel or something? I tried and got UIElement was expected. Thanks

Comment: Where/on what element have you defined `<i:Interaction.Triggers>`?

Comment: I posted this as an answer so you can accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the resource into one of the control that is inside the `DataTemplate`, instead of in the `DataTemplate` itself:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContentDetail">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="500" >
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="StoryCallLogOn">
                <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="gridCallLog">
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0,10,23.04"/>
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0,0,10,200"/>
                </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="borderCallLog">
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,402,10,23.04"/>
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0,225,10,23.04"/>
                </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Border Margin="10,5,0,10" BorderBrush="Transparent" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1" Width="1050">
            <StackPanel Margin="5,5,9,5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <dx:DXTabControl Width="850" Margin="5,5,0,0">
                    <dx:DXTabItem Header="Call Log">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <dxg:GridControl x:Name="gridCallLog" Height="400" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainStack,Path=DataContext.CallLog}"  
                            dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2010Blue" Margin="0,0,10,0" SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=MainStack,Path=DataContext.SelectedCallLog,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                <dxg:GridControl.Columns >
```

Comment: sorry about the delay getting back. YES that seems to kick start the storyboard. Perfect. Thanks